# How to split data when archiving from AWS database to S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-data-pipeline

For a project we've inherited we have a large-ish set of legacy data, 600GB, that we would like to archive, but still have available if need be.

We're looking at using the AWS data pipeline to move the data from the database to be in S3, according to this tutorial.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/datapipeline/latest/DeveloperGuide/dp-object-copyactivity.html

However, we would also like to be able to retrieve a 'row' of that data if we find the application is actually using a particular row.

Apparently that tutorial puts all of the data from a table into a single massive CSV file.

Is it possible to split the data up into separate files, with 100 rows of data in each file, and giving each file a predictable file name, such as:

foo_data_10200_to_10299.csv

So that if we realise we need to retrieve row 10239, we can know which file to retrieve, and download just that, rather than all 600GB of the data.

Answer (score 0):

If your data is stored in CSV format in Amazon S3, there are a couple of ways to easily retrieve selected data:

- **Amazon Athena** is an interactive query service that makes it easy to analyze data in Amazon S3 using standard SQL.
- **S3 Select** (currently in preview) enables applications to retrieve only a subset of data from an object by using simple SQL expressions.

These work on compressed (gzip) files too, to save storage space.

See:

- [Welcome - Amazon Athena](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/APIReference/Welcome.html)
- [S3 Select and Glacier Select – Retrieving Subsets of Objects](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/s3-glacier-select/)